# Changing <asp:ListView> column count from the client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

In an ASP.Net web page I have  where I have set GroupItemCount="4" at design level. Which will be converted to a table with four (4) columns in the presentation. It works perfect.

Now there is a new requirement, allow end users to select the number of columns which he like to see on the page (2, 3 or 4).

For that I have add a new drop down with three options 2, 3 and 4. Upon selection I am setting the selected column count to GroupItemCount="x" on , after that again calling data binding process to it.

```
lstProducts.GroupItemCount = 3;
clearForm();
populateProducts(-1);
```

It works. But it is slow since that data preparation process is doing lots more things with tables.

Can't we accomplish same at the client side? (since we have all needed data inside the table). Using something like jQuery? 
I am new to jQuery someone can please guide me steps to do if possible or else a sample.

Comment: can you post your HTML please

Comment: Post more code for clarification